# Is it possible to pass data using a POST Request to a JS Script without using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, http

I'm working on an Indoor Floor Plan generator, which is basically a JS script that draws the floor plan based on the data provided on an HTML Canvas.

Here's what a basic call to the script I developed looks like:

```
var indoorMaps = indoorMaps({
    floorSections: [
        {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 10,
            height: 10,
            backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
            foregroundColor: "#000000"
        }
    ]
});
```

So basically, I have two clients:

- Mobile (Android, iOS)
- Desktop (Java Crossplatform JAR executable)

How would I be able to call that script in my code if I host it on a web server? I really think it's overkill to add a server-side scripting language like Node just to pass data into it, and I want to explore other possible options, which may suite the application requirements more efficiently.

Comment: What do you mean `call that script` in your code? You mean executing above JS code within your Mobile and Desktop client? or just read the JS code and get necessary parameters structure from it?

Comment: I want to execute the above JS Code.

Comment: Does your client codebase on both platform have the same classes/objects as your JS code, in this case, class/object `indoorMaps`?

Comment: No they don't. All I want to do is pass the data necessary to instantiate the `indoorMaps` object and get the resultant canvas and embed it as a picture.

Comment: Then my opinion is you keep only data under JSON format/JSON file and have your client request and parse data from it.`{
    floorSections: [
        {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 10,
            height: 10,
            backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
            foregroundColor: "#000000"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Yes, that's how I plan to tackle it. How do I pass JSON data to the above script hosted on a static webserver without a server-side scripting language to handle the request?

Comment: You just store only JSON file on static server and serve it with any web server you want like apache, nginx,... Then your client can fetch directly, read the raw JSON and parse it into object

Comment: No, I want to send fresh JSON Data every-time.

Comment: It’s up to you, almost all of web server are able to serve JSON because it’s general communication way for Restful API..It’s nothing to do with server-side scripting language

Comment: Well, how do I send JSON Data to the above script? How would I handle a POST Request without a Form, a pure HTTP Form Request